# How to send 36000 requests within 5 minutes at an RPS of 120 requests using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I am using Jmeter for load testing and I'm new to this. I have an API where I want to send around 36000 requests in a given time, which is- **5 minutes**. What should be the configuration of threads, ramp-up time, loop-count, and constant throughput timer for this scenario?

I am using the following configurations, but I am unable to reach the decided RPS-

```
Thread- 1000
Ramp-up- 5 Minute
loop-count 36
constant throughput timer- 7200
```

Where is my configuration wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to reduce the ramp-up period to be close to zero and increase the number of loops to "infinite", the total number of requests can be limited using [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)

In general there could be 2 main reasons of not being able to conduct the required load:

1. J**Meter cannot produce the desired number of hits per second**. Things to try:

   - Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
   - Increase number of threads in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
   - Consider switching to [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/) mode
2. **Application cannot handle that many requests per second.** Things to try:

   - Inspect configuration and make sure it's suitable for high loads
   - Inspect CPU, RAM, Disk, etc. usage during the load test, it might be simply lack of resources, it can be done using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
   - Re-run your test with [profiler tool telemetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) enabled
   - Raise a ticket as it is a performance [bottleneck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck_(software))

Comment: I see, This makes sense! Thank you for your response. I'll consider moving to distributed testing and profile my code better.